# Display message from Lambda via Javascript after successful form submit

Tags: javascript, python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I'm using [this code](https://www.serverlessops.io/blog/serverless-contact-form-for-static-websites) to add a contact form to my Serverless website (hosted on S3). When an email is successfully sent, the Lambda instance returns the message `"Thank you! You can download the sample here: <a href='https://someurl.com'>Download</a>"`. I want to display that message to the user who submitted the form but I can't figure out how to do so. Currently, my javascript displays a hard-coded message based on the response code from the AWS API Gateway. But I don't want to include the download url in the javascript because I don't want users to be able to see the download without first signing up via the form.

Is there a way to grab the string returned by the Lambda instance and pass it back in the response body and then display that message to the user via javascript?

My current jQuery javascript for the form:

```
    ! function($) {
    "use strict";
    $("form", ".contact-form ").submit(function(t) {
        t.preventDefault();
        var r = !0,
            s = this,
            e = $(s).siblings(".contact-form-result"),
            o;
        // Escape if the honeypot has been filled
        if (!!$("#whatname").val()) return;
        if ($(s).find(":required").each(function() {
                $(this).css("border-color", ""), $.trim($(this).val()) || ($(this).css("border-color", "red"), r = !1);
                var t = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;
                "email" != $(this).attr("type") || t.test($.trim($(this).val())) || ($(this).css("border-color", "red"), r = !1)
            }).keyup(function() {
                $(this).css("border-color", "")
            }).change(function() {
                $(this).css("border-color", "")
            }), r) {
            //var c = $(this).serialize();
            var firstname = $("#name-input").val();
            var lastname = $("#lastname-input").val();
            var mobile = $("#mobile-input").val();
            var email = $("#email-input").val();
            var message = $("#message-input").val();
            var data = {
               firstname : firstname,
               lastname : lastname,
               mobile : mobile,
               email : email,
               message : message }
            $.ajax({
                url: "PATH-TO-AMAZON-API",
                type: "post",
                dataType: "json",
                crossDomain: "true",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: JSON.stringify(data),

                beforeSend: function(data) {
                    $('#submit-mail').attr('disabled', true);
                    //$('#status').html('<i class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin"></i> Sending Mail...').show();
                    o = '<p class="form-message form-success">Sending...</p>';
                    e.removeClass("hidden").html(o)
                },

                success: function (data) {
                    // clear form and show a success message
                    //alert("Successfull");
                    o = '<p class="form-message form-success">Thank you for your message!</p>';
                    e.removeClass("hidden").html(o)
                    $(s)[0].reset();
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        e.addClass("hidden").html("")
                    }, 5e3);
                    $('#submit-mail').removeProp('disabled');
                  },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    // show an error message
                    //alert("UnSuccessfull");
                    o = '<p class="form-message form-error">Sorry, there was an error. Please try again later.</p>';
                    e.removeClass("hidden").html(o)
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        e.addClass("hidden").html("")
                    }, 5e3);
                    $('#submit-mail').removeProp('disabled');
                  }
                });

        }
    })
}(jQuery);
```

And my Python Lambda function (using an API, SES and Dynamo [not currently using Dynamo]):

```
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError
import json
import os
import time
import uuid
import decimal

client = boto3.client('ses')
sender = os.environ['SENDER_EMAIL']
subject = os.environ['EMAIL_SUBJECT']
configset = os.environ['CONFIG_SET']
charset = 'UTF-8'

dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
recipient = 'example@email.com'
def sendMail(event, context):
    print(event)
    #Send mail for contact form
    try:
        data = event['body']
        content = 'Message from ' + data['firstname'] + ' ' + data['lastname'] + ',<br>Phone: ' + data['mobile'] + ',<br>Message Contents: ' + data['message']
        #saveToDynamoDB(data)
        response = sendMailToUser(data, content)
    except ClientError as e:
        print(e.response['Error']['Message'])
    else:
        print("Email sent! Message Id:"),
        print(response['MessageId'])
    return "Thank you! You can download the sample here: <a href='https://someurl.com'>Download</a>"

def list(event, context):
    table = dynamodb.Table(os.environ['DYNAMODB_TABLE'])

    # fetch all records from database
    result = table.scan()

    #return response
    return {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "body": result['Items']
    }

def saveToDynamoDB(data):
    timestamp = int(time.time() * 1000)
    # Insert details into DynamoDB Table
    table = dynamodb.Table(os.environ['DYNAMODB_TABLE'])
    item = {
        'id': str(uuid.uuid1()),
        'firstname': data['firstname'],
        'lastname': data['lastname'],
        'email': data['email'],
        'message': data['message'],
        'createdAt': timestamp,
        'updatedAt': timestamp
    }
    table.put_item(Item=item)
    return

def sendMailToUser(data, content):
    # Send Email using SES
    return client.send_email(
        Source=sender,
        ReplyToAddresses=[ data['email'] ],
        Destination={
            'ToAddresses': [
                recipient,
            ],
        },
        Message={
            'Subject': {
                'Charset': charset,
                'Data': subject
            },
            'Body': {
                'Html': {
                    'Charset': charset,
                    'Data': content
                },
                'Text': {
                    'Charset': charset,
                    'Data': content
                }
            }
        }
    )
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Well, that was easy...after all the searching online for days trying to figure this out. Turns out the message is right there in `success: function (data)` so I all I have to do is return the `data` variable in my javascript. So it would look like this:

```
        success: function (data) {
            // clear form and show a success message
            //alert("Successfull");
            o = '<p class="form-message form-success">' + data + '</p>';
            e.removeClass("hidden").html(o)
            $(s)[0].reset();
            setTimeout(function() {
                e.addClass("hidden").html("")
            }, 5e3);
            $('#submit-mail').removeProp('disabled');
          },
```